# GoLang Error/Interface Mechanism

Tags: go

Firstly, I am not quite sure if this problem is more relevant to error, or to interface in GoLang

I am catching up the GoLang by following the tutorial. The question came with this tutorial [page](https://tour.golang.org/methods/8)

It is a basic demonstration of the error interface. When I change the code a bit like this, I got confused:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf ("at %v, %s", e.When, e.What)
}

func run() *MyError {
    return &MyError{
        time.Now(), "it didn't work",
    }
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    err1 := MyError{time.Now(), "it works again"}
    fmt.Println(err1)
    fmt.Println(err1.Error())
}
```

The output of this piece of code is:

```
at 2015-04-06 15:00:07.1541719 +0800 CST, it didn't work
{2015-04-06 15:00:07.155172 +0800 CST it works again}
at 2015-04-06 15:00:07.155172 +0800 CST, it works again
```

The thing confused me is under what condition the fmt will implicitly call MyError.Error() interface.

To my understanding, the first and second fmt.Println() should have the same variable type: MyError. But obviously the first call involved an implicit call of Error() of the MyError type, while the second did not.

What mechanism made this difference?

Thanks for looking into this beginner's question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code binds the Error() implementation to a pointer *MyError.

In your code you are passing the type (a copy thereof to be precise) rather than a pointer.

If you change

```
err1 := MyError{time.Now(), "it works again"}
```

to

```
err1 := &MyError{time.Now(), "it works again"}
```

it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`fmt.Println` uses reflection to firstly check the type of the variable and if the type implements the `Stringer` interface then it calls the `String` method. Secondly if the type implements the `Error` interface it calls the `Error` method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One more question, for struct type, GoLang has default implementation for stringer, if we implement an error interface, will it confuse the fmt.Println, wondering which interface to use?

Comment: Actually it is the other way around. `Error() string` is used before (in preference to) `String() error`.

Comment: @DaveC Which is funny right? as if you define both `Error() string` there would be no use to define `String() string`, atleast not on a pointer to your type struct...